# How can I move something relative to it's facing at a fixed speed while preventing movement along the global y axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've tried using `transform.translate` with `Space.Self`, but that comes with the problem of moving up or down when the object has any pitch. Using `Space.World` doesn't account for any of the objects facing though, so just that won't work either. I know this is a very simple issue that practically every 3D game has solved, but I haven't for the life of me been able to figure out the solution or find it in any searches.

This is what I currently have:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    float speed = 0.15f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            transform.Translate (0, 0, speed, Space.Self);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            transform.Translate (0, 0, -speed, Space.Self);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            transform.Translate (speed, 0, 0, Space.Self);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            transform.Translate (-speed, 0, 0, Space.Self);
        }
    }
}
```

What I have here presents multiple issues. If the character has any pitch, it will attempt to float straight in that direction instead of moving at full speed horizontally. Additionally, diagonal movement such as when `w` and `s` are held simultaneously will move the character 1 unit along each axis instead of 1 unit in the diagonal.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you give a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what methods are you using to move the `GameObject`? Are you using `Transform`'s methods, or rather `RigidBody`? That would help providing a solutions that fits your case. And what's Space? A library, or some game template? You can edit this question anytime to make it better.

Comment: ...anyway, `Vector3` can be used to define movement. If you are basing the translation on `Transform.translate` using the orientation vector of your camera as a reference, you could supress the "pitch" copying the camera's orientation `Vector3` to another variable, change the vector's `y` property to zero, and THEN use that "no-pitch vector" for `transform.translate`, if I understood well your issue...

Comment: So, `Space.Self` is a constant for `translate` method, so it's relative... so that means you got a parent that provides the local reference. Supposing that parent's orientation is ( 0, 0, 0 ), the above idea would apply as well... but otherwise, angle geometry might become a bit more complicated... but there are some `Vector3`'s operation methods that might help. If I knew more details about your settings, I could think on a less abstract solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your facing direction vector which ignores the Y axis, you can take transform.forward and remove the Y component like this:

```
Vector3 facingDirection = transform.forward;

Vector3 myNewDirectionVector = new Vector3(facingDirection.x, 0, facingDirection.z).normalized;
```

You can then move your object like this:

```
transform.position += myNewDirectionVector * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```